# CSS code to adjust column widths using static name instead of display name

Tags: list, web-part, list-view, css, style.css

I'm currently using this code to adjust the width of specific columns by referencing the display name:

**English version**:

```
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName = "Recent History"]
 {
 width:300px
}
```

However, I've run into a problem where column headers with accents (i.e. French versions) aren't recognized.

**French version**:

```
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName = "Histoire récente"]
 {
 width:300px
}
```

As a results, I'd like to use the static name of the column instead of the display name since all of my columns were first created in English and don't have any accents. But I can't seem to get the code to run.

```
.ms-vh-div[StaticName = "Recent_x0020_History"]
 {
 width:300px
}
```

Any ideas on how to improve my code and/or other workarounds for this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.ms-vh-div[Name="Recent_x0020_History"] { width:300px }
```

There are no `StaticName` property on div elements that use `.ms-vh-div` class. The property `Name` has the value of internal name of the column. So using the property `Name` should solve your problem.